# Android UI: align a fragment above another fragment that is aligned bottom

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments

I haven't developed for `Android` in more than a year and I'm a bit rusty with it. I'm trying to setup a kinda simple `UI`: a bottom bar at the bottom of the screen and a fragment above it (but without filling the whole height). Something like this:

[image]

I thought this would be quite simple, but after a while struggling with it I can't manage to make it work without some "hacks".

The bottom bar is also implemented as a `Fragment`. This is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:name="com.mytestpackage.BottomBarFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `Fragment` in fragmentContainer is dynamically loaded from code. With the code paste above, fragmentContainer is aligned bottom but it's not above bottom bar, they're overlapped. If I remove the `alignParentBottom` from fragmentContainer, then it's placed in top of the screen.

Like I said, I found two "hacks" to solve it but I don't like them much:

1- Set a `padding`/`margin` bottom to fragmentContainer.
2- Use a filler empty layout on top of the screen and set fragmentContainer to be below that one.

Is there any way to achieve the layout I want without having to use some tricks like the ones I said?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the relative layout:

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

Ah, and `android:orientation="vertical"` is meaningless for `RelativeLayout`

A simpler solution would be to use a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation and gravity bottom instead of the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Of course, I forgot about gravity bottom! I feel so dumb! Thank you! :)